# Show that every accumulation point of A is not an interior point of of B.

Tags: real-analysis

Let A be a set and B = R \ A. Show that every accumulation point of A is not an interior point of of B.

Comment: Suppose that A is closed. Let x denote a boundary point of A. Since x is a boundary point, every neighborhood B of x contains a point of A and a point of R n A. Hence, x is not an interior point of R n A. SInce R n A is open, we conclude that x is not a point in R n A. Hence x E A. can i prove it like this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to assume $A$ is closed. If $x$ is an interior point of $B$, then $\exists$ an open set $U$ containing $x$ such that $U \subset B$. Hence, $U\cap A = \emptyset$. But this means that $x$ cannot be an accumulation point of $A$ (else every neighbourhood of $x$ would intersect $A$ non-trivially).